# SQL cummulative sum by group

Tags: sql

I am struggling in finding a solution to create a cumulative sum by group in SQL.

I have a table which have different events. What I want to accomplish is to sum the duration time of an event.

```
CREATE TABLE Events(
  EventID int,
  EventName varchar(20),
  EventTime numeric(17,6)
);

INSERT INTO Events VALUES (1, 'Event1_Start', 0.2);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (2, 'Event2_Start', 0.3);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (3, 'Event3_End', 0.2);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (4, 'Event2_End', 0.6);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (5, 'Event4_Start', 0);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (2, 'Event2_Start', 0.3);
INSERT INTO Events VALUES (6, 'Event1_End', 0);
```

What I need is a cumulative sum that gives me the total duration of Event1 as column besides 'Event1_Start' row.
I would like to sum all the intermediates events before my event_start and event_end.

| EventID | EventName | EventTime | CumSumEvent1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event1_Start | 0.2 | 1.6 |
| 2 | Event2_Start | 0.3 | 0 |
| 3 | Event3_End | 0.2 | 0 |
| 4 | Event2_End | 0.6 | 0 |
| 5 | Event4_Start | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Event2_Start | 0.3 | 0 |
| 6 | Event1_End | 0 | 0 |

I try to use sum over partition but no luck and CTE.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.
Best regards.

Comment: Hello, could you please update the post with expected result?

Comment: @ekochergin updated the result table. Thanks.

Comment: Why rows with EventId=2 are duplicated in your sample? Why Event1_Start contains cumulative sum of values up to Event1_End while Event2_Start contains zero? I would expect you want 1.1 as sum of event times with id between start id and end id.

Comment: Hi @TomášZáluský, the logic behind those rows is that any one of them is an event with its time, so there can be events with the same time. In want to count Event1_Start as the cumulative sum of all the events (any) until Event1_End appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group by part of the string:

```
select substr(eventname, 1, 6), sum(eventtime) from Events group by substr(eventname, 1,6)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d8492b501dc46a88707a8c1165645fb)*

Comment: Hi @tnavidi, thanks for your suggestion, but I am nor getting the desire result. Please check my updated result table. Regards.

Comment: not quite sure what you mean; here is an addition to the *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24e2e154991d7c38a7ab50daa5a87f4d)* where I sum all the eventtimes with eventIDs between event1_start and event1_end

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    EVENTID   "EVENTID",
    EVENTNAME "EVENTNAME",
    EVENTTIME "EVENTTIME",
    CASE
        WHEN EVENTID = 1 THEN Sum(EVENTTIME) OVER() ELSE 0 END "CUMULATIVE_SUM_EVENT_1"
FROM
    EVENTS
```

Comment: Analytic function Sum() (with Case statement in this ansswer) should do the work. You can get a deeper insight on how to use it at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115 (older verssion but ok).